# Selecting colours for vline, such that they match the colour of lines produced with geom_line()

Tags: r, ggplot2

Let's say I'm plotting two densities from the diamonds dataset:

```
d_1 <- subset(diamonds, color %in% c("D", "E"))
ggplot(data = d_1, aes(x = price,colour=color)) + geom_density() + 
      geom_vline(xintercept = 5000) + geom_vline(xintercept = 2500)
```

My question is regarding the ways that I may choose the `vlines` so that they match the colours used for `geom_density` distributions.

I understand that I could use `geom_vline(xintercept = 2500, colour = "red")`, but how can I have `geom_vline` inherit the colours used in the `aes` for the distribution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add new column to the data frame where for each color you set xintercept values

```
d_1$xint<-ifelse(d_1$color=="D",2500,5000)
```

Then you need only one `geom_vline()` call where inside `aes()` you set `xintercept=` to new column and `colour=` to column `color`.

```
ggplot(data = d_1, aes(x = price,colour=color)) + geom_density()+
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept=xint,colour=color))
```

[image]